# Find a design pattern to write less code

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have classes A, B, C:

```
 public class A 
{
    public int Prop1;
    public int Prop2;
    public int Prop3;
    public int Prop4;
    public int Prop5;
}

public class B:A
{
  public int PropB1;
  public int PropB2;
}

public class C:A
{
   public int PropC1;
}
```

I create objects B, C from available variables:

```
var b = new B
{
 Prop1 = param1,
 Prop2 = param2,
 Prop3 = param3,
 Prop4 = param4,
 Prop5 = param5,
 PropB1 = param6,
 PropB2 = param7,
}
var c = new C
{
 Prop1 = param1,
 Prop2 = param2,
 Prop3 = param3,
 Prop4 = param4,
 Prop5 = param5,
 PropC1 = param8
}
```

With this coding style, it has duplicate codes. How to avoid this. Please help me. Thanks.

> ```
>  Prop1 = param1,
>  Prop2 = param2,
>  Prop3 = param3,
>  Prop4 = param4,
>  Prop5 = param5,
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use an array instead of properties? And why no constructor?

Comment: @Tobberoth: I imagine the properties here are just for example. But why you would want to choose an array over a set of strongly typed properties is beyond me. Arrays have their place, but not here

Comment: Use property for my purpose, no array in this case. Thanks. And please remember there are no duplicate codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
public class A 
{
    public int Prop1;
    public int Prop2;
    public int Prop3;
    public int Prop4;
    public int Prop5;

    public A()
    {
    }

    public A(A a)
    {
        this.Prop1 = a.Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = a.Prop2;
        this.Prop3 = a.Prop3;
        this.Prop4 = a.Prop4;
        this.Prop5 = a.Prop5;
    }
}

public class B:A
{
    public int PropB1;
    public int PropB2;

    public B(A a) : base(a)
    {
    }
}

public class C:A
{
    public int PropC1;

    public C(A a) : base(a)
    {
    }
}
```

You can then create your objects like this :

```
var a = new A
{
 Prop1 = param1,
 Prop2 = param2,
 Prop3 = param3,
 Prop4 = param4,
 Prop5 = param5
};

var b = new B(a)
{     
 PropB1 = param6,
 PropB2 = param7
}

var c = new C(a)
{
 PropC1 = param8
}
```

Comment: Still duplicate codes:
`this.Prop1 = a.Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = a.Prop2;
        this.Prop3 = a.Prop3;
        this.Prop4 = a.Prop4;
        this.Prop5 = a.Prop5`

Answer (score 2):

Add constructors to your classes. This saves you the typing of the propertynames when you create an instance.

Like this:

```
public class A  {
    public A(int prop1, int prop2, int prop3, int prop4, int prop5) {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
        Prop4 = prop4;
        Prop5 = prop5
    }
    public int Prop1;
    public int Prop2;
    public int Prop3;
    public int Prop4;
    public int Prop5;
}

public class B : A {
    public B(int prop1, int prop2, int prop3, int prop4, int prop5, int propB1, int propB2) :
        base(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5) {
        PropB1 = propB1;
        PropB2 = propB2
    }
    public int PropB1;
    public int PropB2;
}

public class C : A {
    public C(int prop1, int prop2, int prop3, int prop4, int prop5, int propC1) :
        base(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5) {
        PropC1 = propC1;
    }
    public int PropC1;
}

var b = new B(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7);
var c = new C(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param8);
```

Comment: Yeah, but it is not easy to maintenance because we have a lot of params in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your arguments into another object.

```
class AArg {
  public int prop1;
  public int prop2;
  public int prop3;
  public int prop4;
  public int prop5;
}

class A {
  public A(AArg args) {
     // COPY(!) the values.
     prop1 = args.prop1;
     prop2 = args.prop2;
     prop3 = args.prop3;
     prop4 = args.prop4;
     prop5 = args.prop5;
     prop6 = args.prop6;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public int probB1;
  public B(Aargs aArgs, int probB1) {
    super(aArgs);
    this.probB1 = probB1;
  }
}
```

When you use this pattern, it is important to copy the contents of the argument-wrapper, instead of just saving it as a field. If you don't copy it, changes to one object can affect another if the creator of your objects reuses the arguments:

```
AArg arg = new AArg(1,2,3,4,5);
A a1 = new A(arg);
arg.prob1 = 10;
A a2 = new A(arg);
a2.prob2 = 20
// Now a1.prob1 == 10 and a1.prob2 == 20
```

You can also make the argument object immutable, which makes it safe to store it, but this will make you A/B/C objects (partially) immutable as well.